# How would I get a small Flickr image given a specific tag and user via PHP?

Tags: php, flickr

What I want to do is create a PHP script that will get the first Flickr image it finds that has a specific tag and returns the URL of the the small image (the size above thumbnail). If you are unsure of what I mean by the small size, visit this http://www.flickr.com/photos/napix/3353191223/sizes/s/in/photostream/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Take a look at this follow up question I asked. The answer to this question is in this other question: [How can I get one photo for every Flickr tag by a specific user in one request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603055/how-can-i-get-one-photo-for-every-flickr-tag-by-a-specific-user-in-one-request)

Comment: Nice one. For the sake of completeness would you mind either adding your script, or briefly explaining what one would need to alter in the other answer's script to meet your OP requirement, and then I'll +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.flickr.html

Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

```
function flickr_feed ( $tag ) {
    $f = new phpFlickr("MY API KEY", "MY API SECRET");
    $tags = $f->photos_search(array("tags"=>$tag, "tag_mode"=>"any","per_page"=>"20"));
    $counter="0";
    foreach ($tags['photo'] as $photo) {
        if($counter =="0" || $counter =="5" || $counter =="10" || $counter =="15") { $first = " first"; } else { $first = ""; }
        echo '<div class="flickr-thumb'.$first.'">
                <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://farm'.$photo['farm'].'.static.flickr.com/'.$photo['server'].'/'.$photo['id'].'_'.$photo['secret'].'.jpg" title="'.$photo['title'].'">
                <img src="http://farm'.$photo['farm'].'.static.flickr.com/'.$photo['server'].'/'.$photo['id'].'_'.$photo['secret'].'_s.jpg" alt="'.$photo['title'].'"></a>
            </div>';
        $counter++;     
    }
}
```

Comment: First answer review: +1 but perhaps elaborate on your code, eg what is the meaning of `MY API KEY` and `MY API SECRET`

Comment: @Sepster, the API key and API secret should already be known by someone who is looking at the Flickr API. That's no big deal. However, the answer did not answer the question. The answer lies within the declaration of `phpFlickr` and it's `photo_search` method.

Comment: @TylerCrompton I had upvoted because it looked like a valid answer (but given the downvote I presume it didn't work for you?), but yes thought it could use some detail as your question was phrased such that I (incorrectly, sorry) assumed you might need help beyond a code snippet, as there's no indication that you'd tried or were familiar with the API.